# Resizing text in a div with multiple font sizes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some document in a div that is being displayed, and I want the user to be able to adjust the font size of what is inside it. Some sort of code like this:

```
$("#fontPlusBtn").click(function (){
    $("#textDiv").css("font-size", "*=1.1");
}):
```

How can I resize all the text nodes (which vary in size) proportionally in this div?

**Update: (Working version)**

I combined a few answers here plus altered what I had earlier, so for anyone else stumbling upon this problem later on, here's what I did:

```
var upFontSize = function($obj) {
    $obj.children().each(function(index){
        if($(this).children().length > 0){
            upFontSize($(this));
        }else {
            $(this).css({
                "font-size": function(index, value) {
                    return parseFloat(value) * 1.1;
                },
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: They have to be wrapped in another element to have a different font size. What are they wrapped in?

Comment: #textDiv basically holds any HTML page, like a webview. So it has all the wrappers of a normal HTML document, which in this case are out of my control to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answers your question and accounts for the multiple text sizes, and sizing them accordingly:

...And here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xr2gj/44/

js:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#fontPlusBtn").click(function (){
        $(".textDiv, .textDiv > *").each( function(index){
            $(this).css( {
                "font-size": function(index, value) {
                    return parseFloat(value) * 1.1;
              }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

css:

```
#world{
    font-size: 8pt;
}

#solarSystem{
    font-size: 12pt;
}
#galaxy{
    font-size: 14pt;
}

#universe{
    font-size: 16pt;
}
```

html:

```
<a id="fontPlusBtn" href="#">
    Click to increase font-size
</a>

<div class="textDiv" id="world">
    Hello World!
</div>

<div class="textDiv" id="solarSystem">
    <p><b>Hello Solar System!</b></p>
</div>

<div class="textDiv" id="galaxy">
    <p>Hello Galaxy!</p>
</div>

<div class="textDiv" id="universe">
    <p><div><b><a href="#">Hello Universe!</a></b></div></p>
</div>
```

​You may be able to mix with some of the other answers, but this http://jsfiddle.net/Xr2gj/44/ shows it working just as you specified.

Comment: This works as you would expect if you are using classes for ".textDiv" instead of ID check the jsfiddle link.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as noted in the comments to Ricardo's solution. Any idea what can be fixed?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Xr2gj/43/  I updated the jQuery Selector. This should work for you. If not just let me know some more details

Comment: Hmm, still not working, I think it's because of all my nested divs in the #textDiv that have font-sizes specified further down. Is this a problem of recursion depth?

Comment: Part of my answer is that the textDivs cannot be IDs they have to classes: so not #textDiv (id="textDiv)  but .textDiv (class="textDiv") as long as you do that it should work. just like in the fiddle.  There should be no issue with recursion depth

Comment: Got it! I had to do a bit of fiddling with it to make it work, but it's all working now. I'll update my question, feel free to clean up the code if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

`"As of jQuery 1.6, .css() accepts relative values similar to .animate(). Relative values are a string starting with += or -= to increment or decrement the current value. For example, if an element's padding-left was 10px, .css( "padding-left", "+=15" ) would result in a total padding-left of 25px."`
[reference](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

So to do that you can use a function callback which will return the actual value, then you return the new value.
Like the following.

```
  $("#fontPlusBtn").click(function (){
        $("#textDiv > *").css("font-size", function(i, value) {
            return parseInt(value) * 1.1;
        });
    });
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/a2FKW/3)

Comment: This works great for the div, but it doesn't end up changing anything since elements farther down the DOM tree (text nodes in the div) have varying text-sizes. I assume this is because CSS is applying the most local font-size declaration first, how can I get around this?

Comment: @theeggman85 Check my updated answer, if it doesn't solve update your question with your code.

Comment: Hmm, no dice. I would assume it is because I have more divs inside that div (#textDiv is basically like an html reader) and the updated code seems to only be looking for direct children. Is that why? Would I have to manually recurse down the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Here is example - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZD7gm/17/)

Here is code:

```
$("#fontPlusBtn").click(function (){
    var getNr = parseInt($("#textDiv").css("font-size")) * 1.1;
    $(".textDiv").css("font-size", getNr+"px");
});​
```

Problem is, there isn't any divide or multiply condition in css there is only `+=px` or `-=px`. So what you do is just get the parsed integer from actual element `font-size` and then multiply it, and then apply it.